# Ist dieser Satz korrekt?

Tags: passive

> Das Haus **ist** 1952 gebaut worden.

Why is *ist* used in the sentence above? Is that correct?

Comment: Why do you ask? Do you have doubts? What do you think would be right? I don't see any research efforts in your question.

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE! Your question would have been easier to answer if you had elaborated a bit on your doubts. It's hard for us to infer what you know and what you don't know from this very short question. If the current answer doesn't help you, please edit your question with more of your thought process and what you'd like to know.

Comment: I found the question completely fine as it is, were this community not so strict...

Comment: @Unbekannter Editor: Die Editfunktion für die Frage bitte nicht für Diskussionen missbrauchen. Fehlende Reputation zum Kommentieren muss man sich erarbeiten.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's correct. It's the perfect tense of the passive voice of *bauen*:

> Jemand baut das Haus.

=> Passive voice:

> Das Haus wird gebaut.

=> Perfect tense (*gebaut werden* becomes *gebaut worden sein*):

> Das Haus ist gebaut worden.

Setting a passive voice sentence into perfect tense always introduces a form of *sein* because that's what the passive voice's auxiliary verb  *werden* goes with for its perfect tense.